# How to break a heavy poke team's siege?

Tags: league-of-legends

Last game I was against a team which had massive poke and some sustain. To make things worse they also got baron. With that they could just stay behind their minions and launch skill after skill wiping out big chunks of health every time they hit one of us. In the meantime their minions were covered by their endless skill spam and could take down a turret slowly.

Our team was:
Gnar, Rek'sai, Swain, Graves and Braum.

Theirs was:
Jayce, Nidalee, Xerath, Caitlyn and Sona.
Nidalee was a pretty tanky cat though...

So how to deal with a team (or minions) that is sieging and has a lot of nasty poke?

Comment: split or just dive right on them between minion waves

Comment: They can basically only disengage with sona ult. Hard engage them and it should be an easy team fight with your combo. Tanks, massive CC, AoE damage. You have also look for flashes e.g. and focus champs without flash, less escapes and no defense items.

Comment: Chain your CC together (Gnar ult - W, Rek'Sai tunnel underneath and knockup, Swain with snare, Braum Ult). Focus down Sona cause she's the only form of reliable disengage. Once she's dead just focus the rest.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 like I said in a comment in an answer, they can only disengage with sona ult... and the sheer amount of slows + hastes they have. Right off the bat, they have at least one AoE slow and at least one single target slow that are safe to use (cait e xerath w). Also, Xerath will likely go 40% CDR + Rylais making it hard to actually catch up to him or his team. Add this to Talisman sona with maxed W and Jayce Gate and it becomes pretty hard to catch the enemy team.

Comment: The only hard engage OP's team has is Gnar ult (which is telegraphed), Braum ult (telepgraphed) and RekSai W (telegraphed, melee range). All of these likely rely on flash due to how slow they are *and* the range of jayce/nidalee. You would also need to use 2 at once because otherwise Jayce will just bonk the other target away and then run away with the combined speed of Jayce E, Talisman, Sona W. The enemy team has a LOT more ways of disengage than you are giving them credit for.

Comment: @DanPantry For sure you can consider any champs and its spells, but In easy words: Meta team with tanks vs. Poke combo team of squishies what has not been played anymore since season ~3. There is a reason that the first team is a common matchup while the 2nd one can maybe found in bronze sometimes. Don't forget, Exceptions prove the rule.

Comment: Just remember they were sieging with baron and had us pushed in our base. At that point trying to engage is very, very hard against so much range.

Comment: Furthermore the question isn't related on this particular match since it cannot be undone that he lost that match. However, he wants to be informed about ways to react in the future. And in this case its safe to say that these type of combos are not adviseable.

Comment: What I am trying to point out as I have said in a comment down below is that the way to deal with this sort of team composition is to take more reliable forms of hard engage like Vi or Jarvan 4 *and take reliable, strong waveclear* in your mid lane. Swain's waveclear is okay but it has a long CD (nevermove/ult). Whether or not a team comp is meta or not does not change the facts that team comp B is stronger against team comp A when team comp B don't make positional errors. Team comp A was not set up to waveclear a siege comp, esp against a baroned up cait/xerath combo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With that team, you should have won. Let's split up what you and they have:

### Your Team:

- Gnar: Brutal Engage, Tanky, Much CC
- Rek'Sai: Sneak around with Ult, detect enemies in the area which might poke, good engage too, Average CC
- Swain: Teamfight God, almost unkillable, extremely tanky in extended fights, good CC
- Graves: Extremely huge burst, perfect for engages, no CC
- Braum: Tanky, can block projectiles, stun and a perfect ult for fights, Much CC

### Enemy Team:

- Jayce: Strong Poke, average disengage, no CC
- Nidalee: Strong Poke, Heal, average tankiness, no CC
- Xerath: Stupid strong poke, average CC
- Caitlyn: Average Poke, no CC
- Sona: Low heal, good CC, but extremely squishy

What do we notice first? They have neither any valuable disengage nor a lot of CC to lock you down. While you just have a brutal comps for teamfights and also a lot of CC to lock targets down. You also hat a lot of surprise engages with Rek'Sai and Gnar who could have jumpes over walls to flank the enemy. If Gnar or RekSai are inside, Braum could have jumped to them and Ulted himself, creating a 3 - 4 second CC chain if the spells are placed correctly. Taking out Caitlyn or Xerath in one of those fights would have turned the tides completely in your favor.

There are just 3 reasons why you've lost this:

- You lost the game too early and the enemy had too much of a lead
- Gnar/Rek'Sai didn't have the balls to engage
- The enemy was simply much more skilled than you were

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to explain with the supports.

You have melee supports that have to all in and **kill** enemy from 100 -> 0 (leona, braum)

You have supports that do a lot of ranged **poke** damage. (Zyra, morgana, lulu)

You have supports that have **sustain** and some poke in their kit (sona, soraka)

**Kill beats Sustain beats Poke beats Kill**

*sustain beats poke*:
The sustain lane has weaker poke damage than the poke supports, but after this poke it can heal themselves up, staying at full hp while the poke lane is damage.

*poke beats kill*: poke lane has high damage and also does constantly damage to the kill lane supports. This mean that these kill lane melee supports are often around 50% health and will be killed if the engage.

*kill beats sustain*: sustain heroes usually lack the escape skill and are quite bad at trading, the kill support jumps on a sustain hero and locks him for an easy kill

since your team lacks sustain - it will be quite hard for you to take on a poking team

Comment: OP was talking about a pretty particular team comp/scenario.  It isn't near as simple as you are describing it.  What you are describing is only useful during laning phase.  This scenario is after the laning phase in which you need to figure out how to correctly use your team comp to beat the other.  Most types of team comps can beat any other if they are played correctly.  It's not about a counter at this point.